# Live Stream Transcoding VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm hoping somebody can help me with this. Even if VLC isn't the best way I'm open for other methods. I've tried LiquidSoap but I can't get my scripts to function no matter what the script is.

Anyways, what I need to do is pull an Icecast stream streaming in OGG (on my server), transcode it live, and push it to my same Icecast server under a different mount as MP3/MPEG.

I've taken a look at "Sout" for VLC... But damn is it confusing. I could really use some help here.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are going to lose significant audio quality this way.  I highly recommend encoding both streams at the source.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net)

I assume from your description this is audio-only.

You will also need flumotion-ugly from Zaheer's repository.

You should be able to make it work even with a simple pipeline like

```
flumotion-launch icecast-producer url=http://... ! single-generic-decoder ! mp3-encoder ! shout2-consumer ip=... mount-point-...
```

Use flumotion-inspect to look at properties of components if you want to tune more.